# Diamond inheritance code in C++ not working as expected

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I'm trying to understand the solution to the diamond problem (multiple inheritance) in C++.

I've written this code to better understand the solution but it doesn't behave as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
    void Print()
    {
        printf("A\n");
    }
};

class B : virtual public A
{
public:
    void Print()
    {
        printf("B\n");
    }
};

class C : virtual public A
{
public:
    void Print()
    {
        printf("C\n");
    }
};

class D : public B, public C
{
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.Print();
}
```

Visual studio 2008 express edition yells out :
error C2385: ambiguous access of 'Print'
1>        could be the 'Print' in base 'B'
1>        or could be the 'Print' in base 'C'
error C3861: 'Print': identifier not found

Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: if at all possible, upgrade to the latest Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 1):

Which version of `Print()` should `d.Print()` call? There are two choices. You can choose, though:

```
d.A::Print(); // this one isn't part of the overload set search without qualification
d.B::Print();
d.C::Print();
```

Note that making `A::Print()` a `virtual` function won't help as there is no unique final overriding function. You'd need to explicitly override `Print()` in `D`.

Comment: The example I followed (http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/diamond-problem) suggested that making the inheritance of B and C virtual would solve the problem...